# Inkscape: Dropped shadows are always cut off. How to prevent this?

Tags: inkscape, blur, drop-shadow

When applying a drop-shadow filter in Inkscape, the shadow is totally cutoff and not resized properly. The paths are ungrouped and just a simple connected path that has fill and stroke style.

The shadow shall not be an offsetted shadow, it shall be a glow effect with 5px radius in all directions.

- How do I prevent a cut-off of the dropped shadow?
- How to fix the bounding-box (if there is any)?

[image: cut off shadows]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

After applying drop shadow effect, go to Filters-Filter editor dialog box.At the bottom of the dialog box there is Filter general settings tab for changing the co ordinates & dimensions. Adjust the value until you get a drop shadow following the path without any break.

Image1-Drop shadow with default filter setting values[image: default]

Image2-Drop shadow after changing the coordiantes to -2 & dimensions to 5[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, now I figured out what those dimensions do!

For others: They don't influence where the shadow drops, they are basically just the bounding box for future applied effects.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I just think that the shadow itself should set the dimensions and coordinates automatically making sure it doesn't get cut off by default.

Comment: Thanks! I really wonder, why this has to be set manually...

Comment: Thank you for this, seems like something is on the way to make this easier in the future: https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/1.0#Filters

Answer (score 1):

chanduc's answer can also be applied to other similar situations (not just for the drop shadow filter). Adjusting the coordinates/dimensions of the filter solved my similar problem for a stroke with blur.

This is a good page about the basic usage of custom filter effects: [Inkscape » Filter Effects—Custom » Basic Use](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Filters-BasicUse.html)

This problem is also shown clearly in this youtube video (good example of issue, doesn't show this solution). There's also good info in the comments section: [Inkscape Stroke (Outline) Blur Cut-Off Bug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuRnH1LHa94)