# Inkscape Bounding Box crops Stroke Paint

Tags: inkscape, stroke, corners

I noticed that my corner is being cut off of the bottom node of path when I add a border to it. I believe when adding a border of that thickness to the object/paths on the left the result should be the image on the right.
All of the nodes are connected, and there are only 4 nodes that are symmetrical. 3 on the circle at the top, and one at the triangle's tip at the bottom.

How do I prevent my corner/vertex from being cropped off when adding a stroke?

[image: Left Image is a upside-down tear drop with a black stroke/boarder, Right Image is two tear-drops, a purple one inside a black one]

Comment: I noticed that If I draw a 3-sided polygon (triangle) where the Width is 80 and height is 69.282 & a stroke width of 13.3px. Then shrink it's width to 40.813. The stroke seems uneffected, but If I shrink it once more to 40.812 the stroke at top of triangle is cut off.

Comment: this may be another solution, which can work too when have the same issue when Blur stroke https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55294/inkscape-dropped-shadows-are-always-cut-off-how-to-prevent-this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to increase the mitre value of the stroke.  Increase it until you form the correct mitre join.

Note that if you squish objects by distorting them, you will change the angle of the corner joints affecting the mitre.

[image]

Comment: I searched for a very long time for this -- This is exactly what I was asking. Thank you!

Comment: Finally helped! Thank you Billy Kerr!

Comment: That's really weird because i did as you show but nothing different happened. In my case I'm getting a circle with square borders on top, left, right and bottom.

Comment: Well...in my case I just installed the latest version 1.01 and it works now!

Comment: @samu101108 - this works in older versions of Inkscape too.

Answer (score 0):

If changing `mitre` value of the stroke doesn't work for you, then make sure `Blur` set to `0`.

More information: [Stroke corners cutting off randomly](https://inkscape.org/ar/forums/beyond/stroke-corners-cutting-off-randomly/).